# Applying Callback To One Y-Axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have this part of my chartjs code below, I would like to make the data on y-axis-b always have two decimals even if it's "0", I did some research and found this callback here on Stackoverflow, but it applies to both y-Axes, how can I have it apply to only y-axis-b? Thanks!

```
         options: {
         tooltips: {
       mode: 'index',
       callbacks: {
            label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
                var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';
                return label + ' ' + (Math.round(tooltipItem.yLabel * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
            }
        }

   },
       scales: {
         xAxes: [{
               barPercentage: 0.6,
           ticks: {
             min: 0
           }
         }],
         yAxes: [{
             
             ticks: {
     reverse: false,
     suggestedMax:100,
     beginAtZero: true,
   
   },
           position: "right",
           id: "y-axis-b",
           scaleLabel: {
               display: true,
               }
         }, {
              gridLines : {
               drawOnChartArea: false
           },
             scaleLabel: {
               display:true,
               }, 
           position: "left",
           id: "y-axis-a",
           ticks: {
            suggestedMax: 1500,
            suggestedMin: -1500
            
           } 
               
         }]
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `label` in `options/tooltips/callbacks`, use `ticks` in `options/scales/y` like [this example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/labelling.html).

So your code becomes:

```
options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    // Customize your label here
                    callback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return value.toFixed(2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```